# Javascript - Get substring that comes after "string1" and before "string2"

Tags: javascript, string, substring

When making a fetch to a certain URL, I am getting an HTML page in the format of text as I wanted.

Inside of it, there are plenty of `id=(...)"` and I require one of them

So I am asking, how could I get an array with all the strings that come after "**id=**" and before the " **"** "?

I made some tries such as :

```
var startsWith = "id="
var endsWith = "\""
var between = fullString.slice(fullString.indexOf(startsWith), fullstring.indexOf(endsWith))
```

but couldn't get it to work.

Any suggestions are welcome

Comment: It really looks like you're going about this the wrong way.  What is the response you're receiving?

Comment: It is indeed the wrong way, In this example case I would get an empty result

Comment: **What is the response you're receiving?**  I highly, *highly* doubt you should be using substring operations here, at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the following regex: /id=\"(.*?)\"/gmi.

The code will be as such:

`fullString.match(/id=\"(.*?)\"/gmi)`

The result will be an array of `id="your id"`

and then you can do the following:

`var between = fullString.match(/id=\"(.*?)\"/gmi).map(str => str.substr(str.indexOf('id=\"') + 'id=\"'.length).slice(0, -1))`

Answer (score 0):

Why you dont use a plugin like jquery? Please refer to this example:

```
var fullString = "<y>your cool html</y>";
var $html = $(fullString);
var stuffInside = $(html).find('#yourId');

console.warn('stuffInside:', stuffInside.html());
```